# Deploy in Google app Engine Launcher doesn't always work

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

I am using the Google App Engine Launcher to browse and deploy my applications.

I can always browse my application locally

When I click on deploy, the log window tells me that deployment has succeeded. But despite this, most of the time, when I go to name.appspot.com, I don't see the updated version of my application. Instead I see some older version. So it seems like deployment didn't work. I have tried opening up the same application in another browser and get the same result. As far as I can tell, deployment sometimes works, but usually not. I don't see any pattern in when it works and when it doesn't.

What could be wrong? I'm using Windows 8.

Comment: This doesn't contain enough information to answer, as it could be a number of things. Is it possible you don't compile your WAR? (not being sure which language you use, this is hard to tell) Could also be that you have a default version that you don't change? There are a number of things that could happen here. We would need more info into what you do, what exactly happens when. Stating "most of the time" is not a helpful metric to anyone trying to help you :(. Honestly, I'd check the version and make sure I compile prior to deploy.